# Apple App Store Promotional Text Not Shown

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an app published on Apple App Store. App Store Connect has optional text field labeled as ”Promotional Text”. I want to use it and enter my text. The text appears on the App Store (takes some time but eventually) but only when the App Store language matches the app language.

My app supports only one language (English) and thus I can enter the Promotional Text only to the English locale.

When I set my phone language to English I can see the promotional text fine.

When I set my phone language to any other language the promotional text is not shown. All other information about my app is shown normally. They are in English and all other texts of the App Store  app are shown in selected language as should be.

I don’t see any reason why promotional text should not be shown with same language rules as for example the Description of What’s New is shown.

Is there something I’m missing here? Is only way to get the Promotional Text shown to copy my English descriptions, etc., to all languages the App Store supports?

Comment: I have found the same behavior, on Mac App Store. The text, appears, however, on the Web ("Preview"), even for locales on that I don't have localizations for.